# Nutiteq in Android Studio 0.8.14

Tags: android, nutiteq

I was trying to use `Nutiteq SDK 3.0` with android studio but I can't get it to work.

All libraries are added, but in layout file when using:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.nutiteq.ui.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

it throws an error:

```
> Rendering problems:

The following classes could not be instantiated:

    - com.nutiteq.ui.MapView

    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nutiteq_maps_sdk in java.library.path
```

If i import in some class file, it works well and don't give any error
any help?

Comment: I have Android Studio 0.8.9 for Mac and imported hellomap example project to it (using import Eclipse project). It seems to work fine, you can check the structure and versions of the plugins, NDK .so library must be in correct folder. I put my imported working project temporarily here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3573333/com.nutiteq.hellomap3.zip , maybe it helps

Comment: Even with that it wont work :S I don't know what could be wrong..

Comment: do you have exactly same version of android studio, Gradle and other related tools?

Comment: Do you have something else in lgocat about nutiteq_maps_sdk, during application startup? It looks like the .so file is not compiled in properly, it is missing from right folder, or AS searches it from wrong folder.

Comment: I am using Gradle 2.1 and the example works for me.

I downloaded JaalL's example from dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3573333/com.nutiteq.hellomap3.zip and changed the following things:
1) Deleted the autogenerated "local.properties" file from the "app" module
2) Set classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0' in the main build.gradle (you need gradle plugin 0.14.0 for Gradle 2.1)
3) Set the buildToolsVersion "21.1.1" in the "app" module build.gradle
4) Installed the app by "gradle clean installDebug"

PS: Make sure your Android SDK is up-to-date and you have Build Tools 21.1.1

Comment: I solved my problem here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nutiteq-dev/jtyvl4EYJ_0